# Post Method vb.net HttpClient

Tags: vb.net, post

I am trying to create a Post method in an older Program we have that uses VB.net. When I get down to the PostAsync method the program stops running and I never receive any sort of error message. Do I even have this set up correctly? Here is my code.

```
Public Class EmailService


    Public Async Function SendEmailAsync(errorMessage As String) As Task
        Dim uri = "myFunction"
        Dim xFxnKey = "myXFunctionsKey"
        Dim mailTo = "someMailingAddress"
        Dim subject = "Subject"

        Dim message = $"{{""To"": ""{mailTo}"", ""Subject"": ""{subject}"", ""Body"": ""{errorMessage}"", ""Source"": ""ProgramSource"", ""Attachments"": []}}"

        Dim content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)
        Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)
        Dim bytes = New Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(buffer)
        bytes.Headers.ContentType = New Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
        bytes.Headers.Add("x-functions-key", xFxnKey)

        Dim responseBody As String = Nothing
        Using client As New System.Net.Http.HttpClient
            Try
                Dim response = Await client.PostAsync(uri, bytes)
                responseBody = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: In your Try, Catch, add the following after Catch ex as Exception... Response.Body = ex.Message This will show you a basic error message if an exception occurred... It maybe that that an exception occurred but you're not processing it?